# extjs export to excel not working in IE

Tags: jsp, extjs

Im using extjs Ext.grid.GridPanel in jsp , in that Export to Excel functionality not working in IE. It's working in FireFox and chrome.

Code:

```
window.location='data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + Base64.encode(grid.getExcelXml());
```

Kindly any one give me the solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue with following code .

```
var vExportContent = grid.getExcelXml();
var dataURL = 'export.jsp';
params =[{
          name: 'ex',
          value: vExportContent 
          },{
          name: 'FileName',
          value: 'excel.xls'
           }];
 post_to_url(dataURL, params, 'post');



function post_to_url(path, params, method) {
     method = method || "post"; 
     var form = document.createElement("form");
     form.setAttribute("method", method);
     form.setAttribute("action", path);
     for(var i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
         var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
         hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
         hiddenField.setAttribute("name", params[i].name);

         hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[i].value);  
       //  alert(params[i].value);

         form.appendChild(hiddenField);
     }   

     document.body.appendChild(form);   

     form.submit();

 }
```

export.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>  

<%
 response.setHeader("Pragma","public");
 response.setHeader("Expires","0");
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 response.setHeader("Content-Type","application/force-download");
 response.setHeader("Content-Type","application/vnd.ms-excel");
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export2excel.xls");

%>

<%@ page import="java.io.*"  %>

<%
String h=request.getParameter("ex");
try {
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();

    //out.println(request.getParameter("ex"));
    pw.println(request.getParameter("ex"));


    //clean up
    pw.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
   out.println(e.getMessage());
}

%>
```

Comment: See [this page by Steve Drucker](http://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/generate-an-excel-file-from-an-ext-js-4-grid/) for the definition of `getExcelXml()` (used in the above solution).

Answer (score 0):

Can you check Security Level Settings for IE.

Custom Level->Security Settings->Downloads->Automatic prompting for file downloads->Enable

Enable this option to allow you to download the file otherwise it will not working just open the windows and close immediately. You cannot identify what happened.

I hope it is working solution for you.